# Sort query results by Field1 Field2 Field3 ASC and DESC so

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Sort query results by Field1 Field2 Field3 ASC and DESC so

Hello friends, I need the help I can get, I have a filter on my site and let me know how I can sort the results leaked to the mysql database and so Field1 Field2 Field3 ASC and DESC

and desire to create the value of selection option on the form for users to decide whether ASC or DESC order filter and option value for each field selection

```
          <?php

$o      = '';
// Pon la información correspondiente:
$data   = array( 'localhost', 'user', 'password' );
$con    = mysql_connect( $data[0], $data[1], $data[2] );

if( ! $con ) {
    $o = 'Error: no se pudo conectar con el servidor. ' . mysql_error();
    echo $o;
    exit;
}

// Cambia el nombre de la base de datos por la tuya
$db_name = 'database';

if( ! mysql_select_db( $db_name, $con ) ) {
    $o = 'Error: no se pudo seleccionar la base de datos "' . $db_name . '". ' . mysql_error();
    echo $o;
    exit;
}

$table = 'users'; // Cambia este SÓLO si sabes lo que hace.
$query = "SELECT * FROM $table";
$where = " WHERE";
$and     = 0;


if( isset( $_GET['Nombre'] ) && ! empty( $_GET['Nombre'] ) ) {
    $where .= " Nombre LIKE '%$_GET[Nombre]%'";
    $and        = 1;
}

if( isset( $_GET['Tarifa'] ) ) {
    $e = explode( ' - ', $_GET['Tarifa'] );

    if( is_numeric( $e[0] ) && is_numeric( $e[1] ) ) {
        if( $and === 1 )
            $where .= " AND";


        $where .= " Tarifa BETWEEN $e[0] AND $e[1]";
        $and        = 1;
    }
}

if( isset( $_GET['Edad'] ) ) {
    $e = explode( ' - ', $_GET['Edad'] );

    if( is_numeric( $e[0] ) && is_numeric( $e[1] ) ) {
        if( $and === 1 )
            $where .= " AND";


        $where .= " Edad BETWEEN $e[0] AND $e[1]";
        $and        = 1;
    }
}

if( isset( $_GET['Estatura'] ) ) {
    $e = explode( ' - ', $_GET['Estatura'] );

    if( is_numeric( $e[0] ) && is_numeric( $e[1] ) ) {
        if( $and === 1 )
            $where .= " AND";


        $where .= " Estatura BETWEEN $e[0] AND $e[1]";
        $and        = 1;
    }
}

if( isset( $_GET['Peso'] ) ) {
    $e = explode( ' - ', $_GET['Peso'] );

    if( is_numeric( $e[0] ) && is_numeric( $e[1] ) ) {
        if( $and === 1 )
            $where .= " AND";


        $where .= " Peso BETWEEN $e[0] AND $e[1]";
        $and        = 1;
    }
}

if( isset( $_GET['Ciudad'] ) && !empty( $_GET['Ciudad'] ) ) {
    if( $and === 1 )
        $where .= " AND";

    $where .= " Ciudad = '$_GET[Ciudad]'";
    $and        = 1;
}

if( isset( $_GET['Ojos'] ) && !empty( $_GET['Ojos'] ) ) {
    if( $and === 1 )
        $where .= " AND";

    $where .= " Ojos = '$_GET[Ojos]'";
    $and        = 1;
}

if( isset( $_GET['Cabello'] ) && !empty( $_GET['Cabello'] ) ) {
    if( $and === 1 )
        $where .= " AND";

    $where .= " Cabello = '$_GET[Cabello]'";
    $and        = 1;
}




if( strlen( $where ) > 6 )
    $query .= $where;

$result = mysql_query( $query, $con);



if( $result ) {
    $nrows  = mysql_num_rows( $result );

    if( $nrows > 0 ) {
        $o = '';

        while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) {

            $o .= "$row[Imagen]";
        }

        $o .= "";
    } else {
        $o = 'No hubieron resultados';
    }
} else {
    $o = 'Error: no se ejecutó la consulta. ' . mysql_error( $con );
}

mysql_free_result( $result );
mysql_close( $con );
echo $o . "";
exit;
       ?>
```

Comment: although i dont really got what you are trying to achieve. The code is really bad practice. Please read about sql enjections and how to prevent. [link]http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Answer (score 0):

To achieve sorting you could add a `order by` clause where you can specify the field by which you want to sort the selection.

If you want to let the user decide how to sort you could add a request parameter which specifies the ascending or descending ordering. Morover you could add a request parameter "field" which you could use to let the user decide what field he wants the selection to be sorted by.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY  Field1 ASC,Field2 DESC,Field3 ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont quite understand the question, if you dont know how to give the user an option to sort, you can use a listbox with multiple selection, and the you look for "TRUE" in each item.
That is explained here:
http://www.abbeyworkshop.com/howto/lamp/php-listbox/index.html

There are a lot of ways of implementing that, this is what I think will work.
Another would be to have combos, so you select what to filter first, and then a combo to select asc or desc, then another combo and so on...you POST that and look for the text in those combos to make the query string.